# Travel from Tokyo to Sendai with Shinkansen

Tags: trains, japan, japan-rail

I need to travel from Tokyo (Tokyo station or Shinjuku station) to Sendai but I am very confused on if I can take the Shinkansen train. I do not want a rail pass for many trains or many days since I am not there for tourism but all I can find is info about passes.

The question is how can I book in advance a Shinkansen train ticket to Sendai?

Comment: Of course you can take the Shinkansen, why not?

Comment: If you don't want to read anything, go to Ueno Station or Tokyo Station and let the staff there do it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments. I see, so no need to book anything online or so. Is that correct?